# Playing audio stream not showing in pavucontrol

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

My Pulse Audio Volume Control (pavucontrol) is not shown  volume bar which present below the volume control slider for right and left channels in the Play tab . However, I can hear audio,and the pavucontrol Play tab shows the name of the application(any media player vlc,mplayer etc.) which is running and volume control for right and left channels (FROM LEFT & FROM RIGHT Volume slider) .  I am attaching screen shot when I am listening songs.

I guess there may be a change in the system configuration/setting? How to reset it?

I have reinstalled Pulseaudio, but the problem remains.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 with default pulse audio.
[image: play back tab]
[image: output tab]

Comment: when run media player then play tab show name of media player name and volume control for right and left channels but below this  one bar is present for showing audio,is not working

Comment: Sorry for me not having been clear enough. Please [edit] your question to include the **Name** (and version) of your media player. Please also add your Ubuntu version, and the version of pulseaudio (if different from default).

Comment: I edited question but still any problem please comment

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution, it was a simple case of the monitor being muted.
In pavucontrol go to input devices, then in the show button at the bottom switch it to All input devices. I believe it's normally set to all except monitors, so the monitor doesn't show up. In my case it was this monitor that was muted, but I could still hear sound because the internal audio wasn't muted.
Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Pavucontrol is not configurable other than it saves it's windows dimensions in `~/.config/pavucontrol.ini` after program termination to open it with the same size next time. However it usually will increase the windows height adapting to needs when there are more lines to display. Factors which may possibly lead to a wrong windows height may come from larger fonts in our theme.

The only instance I was able to reproduce a missing volume meter was when the windows geometry was smaller than needed:

[image]

In this case we can either increase the windows size manually, or we can scroll down the application area to reveal the hidden VU meter:

[image]

If this still does not give us a VU meter for reasons unknown to me we may as workaround install and run [pavumeter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavumeter) [image: Install pavumeter] to display the output volume of a playing stream.

Comment: I have the same problem. Neither pavucontrol nor pavumeter show any VU meter / volume bar. Resizing did not help at all.
In addition, it seems not possible to record any audio in Audacity, because "Monitor of internal audio" does not seem to get any signal ...

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this little problem that VU meter doesn't show anything, including `pavumeter`. The problem is that only "monitor of card" has a volume control. So sometimes it is appears to be muted.

Restore the volume level of "monitor of", which is in the *Input Devices* tab of `pavucontrol`, and everything will work as before.